# React-Router - Back Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there a way I can prevent the url from changing when the back button is clicked?

I'm currently using `createMemoryHistory` to prevent url modification when I navigate around clicking links set up in my app. By doing this, I'm able to successfully navigate around but when I click the back button in my browser, it modifies the url (which I don't want).

E.g. My url looks like `localhost:3000`. Then I click on the `settings` link and I navigate to the settings view but my link is still `localhost:3000`. Now in `settings`, I click on `Printers` and navigate to the `Printers` view inside `settings`. My url still looks like `localhost:3000`. However, if I click the back button and return to the settings page, now my url looks like `localhost:3000/settings`.

Is there anything . I can do to the prevent the back button from modifying my url? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `react-router`'s `browserHistory` class like this:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

//... inside your component class

componentDidMount() {
    browserHistory.listen(location => {
        if (location.action === "POP") {
            // Do your stuff
            // maybe use your `createMemoryHistory` API 
            // to push a / to the history to keep the URL the same?
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that `browserHistory` is no longer available in React Router v4+.